# Mechanics- Polar Co-ordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics

Recently we were taught about uniform circular motion and polar co-ordinates.

For our homework we got an assignment with the position vector of an ellipse, expressed with $t$ as time.
e.g. $4 \cos(2t) \hat{i} + 3 \sin(2t) \hat{j}$

We haven't really covered ellipses before and have just started this mechanics module. We are supposed to find the magnitude of the radial and transversal components of the velocity in polar co-ordinates, when $t$ is equal to a specific number.

I have no idea how to derive an equation for $r$ and $\theta$ for an ellipse and thus derive the velocity expressed by radial and transversal components. I am just curious as to how one would find the $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x = 4cos(2t)$$
$$y = 3sin(2t)$$
Can you find polar coordinates now?
$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$tan \theta = y/x$$

Comment: Thank you! I actually did find this... but for some reason I thought it was wrong, I can't even remember why. Maybe it's because I was working at 11pm ahahaha.